# How can I get my UWP app to differentiate between two identical USB devices?

Tags: uwp, usb

I'm writing a UWP app that interfaces with two microcontrollers (Teensy 3.2 and 3.6), each programmed to do different things. When programmed as serial devices, both uC's VID and PID are always 0x16C0 and 0x0483, respectively.

From the IDE, I can change their type, to any of the following:

[image: available USB types]

When they're both programmed as serial devices, they show up in the UWP serial sample app like so:

[image: USB devices]

You'd think this would allow me to differentiate between the two based on everything after the PID, however, they seem to switch places every other time I start the app. It's frustrating. Furthermore, when I connect to either of them, the part in braces is always the same:

[image]

I've tried changing the type to various things, and I'm mostly able to talk to both devices but they show up in device manager as whatever I make them, and I'm concerned that this might cause conflicts with the rest of my system. For example, setting it as an "All of the Above" device allows my computer to see it as audio, which caused Hulu to crash when it tried to send digital audio to a microcontroller. I'd like to have them both as serial devices, if possible?

Is there any other identifying property I can use to hard-code my app to recognize my devices? I will be running this app on a dedicated computer.

Comment: `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` is always the same as `86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73` and it is by design, you could the this document for the [detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-comport). The different part is in front of GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I know the different part in front of the `86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73`, but it switches between the two devices every time I start the app, restart my computer, or reconnect the devices.

Comment: Do you means the device id is not match with the physical device?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT no, I mean all the attached devices' AQS are identical.

Comment: could you explain the first screenshot, and how do you change the type with IDE?

Comment: That's the Arduino IDE with Teensyduino add-in. By selecting different types, it programs the boards with a different PID.

Comment: Ok, I get it, Can you tell your uwp app's min and target version and your OS version. And have you  checked the `DeviceInformation.Id` of each device and find out what this property is showing for each device?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'm on 18363.720. Target/min is 18362/17134. When programmed as serial devices, both boards return identical strings from DeviceInformation.Id.

Comment: Can you tell which code sample that you have used in this case screenshot?

Comment: Please check if the information in these properties is also duplicated for each device?
`public string Id { get; }`
`public string Name { get; }`
`public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }`
`public DeviceInformationKind Kind { get; }`

Comment: The part after the PID is the serial number of the device.If Windows enumerates two USB devices with the same VID/PID/SN it generates a serial number to be able to distinguish the devices. The first serial number looks like an autogenerated number, the second one looks like a normal serial number but it somehow is too long for a Teensy serial number. Can it be that this is not a standard Teensy?

Comment: @LutzNiggl they're both homebrew, but I'm using the official teensy bootloader chips.

Comment: The bootloader chip won't generate the serial number. Try to set the serial number manually in the core lib and check if it shows up in the deviceid string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the PID is the serial number of the device. Since you have a homebrew board without built in serial number Windows can not distinguish two devices and assigns an auto generated serial number.

The serial number is stored in the struct `usb_string_serial_number` which is defined weak and can be overridden by user code. So, you can easily provide your own serial number by adding the following code to your sketch or in a separate *.cpp file.

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    struct usb_string_descriptor_struct
    {
        uint8_t bLength;
        uint8_t bDescriptorType;
        uint16_t wString[10];
    };

    usb_string_descriptor_struct usb_string_serial_number =
        {
            22,
            3,
            {'M','Y', 'S','N', '0', '0', '0','0', '1', 0},
    };
}


void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWriteFast(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalReadFast(LED_BUILTIN));
  delay(200);
}
```

After uploading Windows reports the following deviceId:

[image]

**Please note:**
The bootloader still reports the "old" serial number which confuses some uploaders (e.g. tyTools). The stock Teensy uploader (Teensy.exe) handles this without problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Not even the folks over at the Teensy forums were able to solve this so elegantly.